# Как увеличить offset для elasticsearch?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Эластик имеет настройку `index.max-result-window` по дефолту равную 10000, поэтому при запросе с offset > 10000, я получаю ошибку. Погуглил проблему, есть разные варианты решений: увеличить `index.max-result-window`, использовать `scroll` или `search_after` но я запрашиваю из эластика не более 100 элементов, поэтому вопрос - что лучше использовать, если offset может быть большим, но количество запрашиваемых документов небольшое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Категорически не рекомендую в качестве решения использовать `index.max-result-window`, это чревато большим потреблением памяти и снижением производительности. Если вы реализуете пагинацию, то используйте `search_after`. `scroll` так же не рекомендую использовать для глубоких запросов (охватывающий более 10000 элементов), к тому же после его использования его надо удалять (по идентификатору скролла) и он может со временем протухнуть.
Если же задача заключается в другом, то советую вам пересмотреть свой подход к индексированию, таким образом, чтобы при каком либо запросе не пришлось так глубоко опускать в глубь. К примеру, разбить индексы на какие-либо группу (по дням, месяцам, типам) исходя из ваших бизнес кейсов.

Comment: не подскажите, как можно избежать получения лишних данных, например, если мне нужно получить 100 элементов с оффсетом 99000, чтобы мне не грузить по сети все предыдущие страницы. Если в ```search_after``` передать дату, после которой нужно вернуть документы и при этом в запросе указать ненулевой оффсет, то эластик вернет ошибку